# Sshuttle: DNS not forwarding

Tags: ubuntu, bind

I have Sshuttle running on a Raspberry Pi 3. The intention is to use the Pi IP as a gateway so I can connect any networked device to Shuttle just by changing the gateway address to that of the Pi.
All that works perfectly fine if I set a DNS up on each device (e.g. 8.8.8.8)
If I set no DNS, or the IP of the Pi as the DNS, I get no data throughput.
I have Shuttle connected to a remote Ubuntu 16.04 server. I don't know if I need to set up a DNS server, such as BIND on that or not - Do I?
I have tried setting up BIND but all I know about that is what I can glean via the Net.
I definitely want to forward my DNS requests so that all traffic goes via Sshuttle.
Any helpful advice will be appreciated.

Comment: is a DNS server available on a more specific route than the default gateway?

Answer (score 0):

This is the main thing you need to add:

```
forwarders {
        8.8.8.8; #example dns servers
        8.8.4.4;
};
forward only;
```

into `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`. Anyways, this simple step is not recommended if your Pi is somehow accessible from the Internet.

I'd suggest [reading this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-16-04).